# Error messages from Salesforce managed package when uploading change set validating running all tests

Tags: salesforce

We recently refreshed our SF development org and I am trying to upload some new work (unrelated to Agile Accelerator managed package) to the org. I am running all tests on validation and getting a number of error messages on a number of ADM classes from the managed package for Agile Accelerator.

Here are a few of the error messages:

When looking at the object I can't find any field called ProfileId, or any reference to a ProfileId for a User. Obviously since the package is managed I can't get inside the code to determine where the issue lies.
Any help? Any idea of where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pasted any errors... When you validate, which option you select?

Running all local tests should be enough. don't bother running all tests including managed package ones, it's almost guaranteed they'll fail (when package inserts new account it'll have no idea about your custom fields, your required, your validation rules...)

If you have run local tests and got errors - well, maybe there are few fields package added that now you have to populate to successfully insert? Generally see what successfully saves in UI and try to replicate that in test?

Comment: Ack sorry thought I had:

ADM_AgeOfWorkTests | testTotalAgeWhenClosed | System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a2V8H000000B8dyUAC; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, When Status = Closed, the following fields are required: Deployed Resolution, Release Notes, Scheduled Build: []Stack Trace: (agf) 

ADM_ApplicationApprover_TriggerTest | testApplicationApproverTrigger | System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]: [ProfileId]Stack Trace: (agf)

Comment: My boss is requiring run all tests. I am trying to convince otherwise.

Comment: Run all tests in prod (just like that, not related to changeset). If you prove that managed package breaks already and you're not making situation worse (or that breaking only managed package tests doesn't block deployment, only your local tests matter) they might change the decision. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm "When deploying to production, all tests, except those that originate from managed packages, are executed"